# TableLayoutPanel place label control inside column

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

With all the properties for TableLayoutPanel, I don't know why this can't be simple.

I have a tableLayoutPanel with two columns. I am trying to place a label inside the first columns to use it as the heading. I want to place it in a specific coordinates relative to the column, but I don't know how except to use the margins or padding properties. There is gotta be a simpler way than that. I have tried using the anchor and dock properties but no avail.

Can someone show me an example of how this can be done? Why can't I just drag the label to where I want it to be?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Set the label's TextAlign property to MiddleCenter.

Comment: +1 for Hans Passant, but to add, I prefer docking the label inside the TableLayoutPanel (Dock.Fill) first, then using the TextAlign property.  I am generally quite hesitant about providing an absolute location for a control inside of a TableLayout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `TableLayoutPanel` you can only put a single control in any cell, and the control will be placed at the top-left corner of the cell. As you've found, one of  the options is to set the control's `Margin` property.

Another option is to put a `Panel` inside the cell, dock it to fill the cell, and place other controls inside the panel. This way you have full control over the placement of the control.

This increases the levels of hierarchy of controls, but that's not a problem unless it reaches to about 10 levels of nesting. That's when you may start encoutering slowness in resizing the form, or even [some strange behaviour](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953934).